# In what case adding an ID field to a many-to-many table might be a good idea?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

Let's say there are two entities - `Product` and `Image` with a many-to-many relationship between them. The order of images associated with each product does matter.

```
Product
------------------------------------
ProductID (primary key)
ProductName
...

Image
------------------------------------
ImageID (primary key)
Url
Size
...
```

What are the cons and pros of the following three many-to-many "bridge" table approaches for solving this problem?

```
ProductImage
------------------------------------
ProductImageID (primary key, identity)
ProductID (foreign key)
FullImageID (foreign key)
ThumbImageID (foreign key)
OrderNumber
```

or

```
ProductImage
------------------------------------
ProductID (primary key, foreign key)
IndexNumber (primary key)
FullImageID (foreign key)
ThumbImageID (foreign key)
```

or

```
ProductImage
------------------------------------
ProductID (primary key, foreign key)
FullImageID (primary key, foreign key)
ThumbImageID (foreign key)
OrderNumber (index)
```

Comment: Why 3 different dbms product tags?

Comment: There is no "better", both of those can have their advantages and disadvantages and SO is probably not the right place to start a flamewar on substitute primary keys.

Comment: @JakubKania, you don't understand, this is not about starting a flamer but figuring out the list of cons and pros for each of the two solutions mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @KonstantinTarkus Wars are often unintended.

Answer (score 3):

There is no purpose (that I have ever found) in adding a surrogate key (i.e. the `IDENTITY` field) to a many-to-many "bridge" table (or whatever you want to call it). However, neither of your proposed schemas is correct.

In order to get the ideal setup, you first need to determine the scope / context of the following requirement:

> The order of images associated with each product does matter.

Should the ordering of the images be the same, in relation to each other, regardless of what Products they are associated with? Meaning, images A, B, C, and D are always in alphabetical order, regardless of what combination of them any particular Product has.

Or, can the ordering change based on the Product that the Image is associated with?

If the ordering of the Images needs to remain consistent across Products, then the `OrderNumber` field needs to go into the Image table. Else, if the ordering can change per Product, then the `OrderNumber` field go into this bridge / relationship table.

In either case:

- the PK is the combination of FKs:

  A Primary Key uniquely, and hopefully reliably (meaning that is doesn't change), identifies each row. And if at all possible, it should be meaningful. Using the combination of the two FK fields gives exactly that while enforcing that uniqueness (so that one Product cannot be given the same Image multiple times, and vice-versa). Even if these two fields weren't chosen as the PK, they would still need to be grouped into a UNIQUE INDEX or UNIQUE CONSTRAINT to enforce that data integrity (effectively making it an "alternate key"). But since these IDs won't be changing (only inserted and deleted) they are well suited to be the PK. And if you are using SQL Server (and maybe others) and decide to use this PK as the Clustered index, then you will have the benefit of having both ProductID and ImageID in any Non-Clustered Indexes. So when you need to sort by `[OrderNumber]`, the Non-Clustered Index on that field will automatically be a covering index because the only two data fields you need from it are already there.

  On the other hand, placing the `[OrderNumber]` field into the PK has a few downsides:

  - It can change, which is not ideal for PKs.
  - It removes the ability to enforce that a ProductID and ImageID can only relate to each other *one time*. Hence would need that additional UNIQUE INDEX or UNIQUE CONSTRAINT in order to maintain the data integrity. Else, even if you include all 3 fields in the PK, it still allows for the ProductID + ImageID combination to be there multiple times per various values of IndexID.
- there is no need for an IDENTITY field:

  With the above information in mind, all of the requirements of a PK have already been met. Adding a surrogate key / auto-increment field adds no value, but does take up additional space.

  And to address the typical reply to the above statement regarding the surrogate key not adding any value, some will say that it makes JOINs easier if this combination of ProductID+ImageID needs to be Foreign Keyed to a child table. Maybe each combination can have attributes that are not singular like `[OrderNum]` is. An example might be "tags" (although those would most likely be associated with just ImageID, but it works as a basic example). Some people prefer to only place a single ID field in the child table because it is "easier". Well, it's not easier. By placing both ImageID and ProductID fields in the child table and doing the FK on both back to this PK, you now have meaningful values in the child table and will not need to JOIN to this `[ProductImage]` table all of the time just to get that information (which will probably be needed in most queries that are not simply listing or updating those attributes for a particular ProductID+ImageID combination). And if it is not clear, adding a surrogate key still requires a UNIQUE INDEX or UNIQUE CONSTRAINT to enforce the data integrity of unique ProductID+ImageID combinations (as stated above in the first bullet point).

  And placing both ID fields into the child table is another reason to stay away from fields that can change when choosing a PK: if you have FKs defined, you need to set the FK to `ON UPDATE CASCADE` so that the new value for the PK propagates to all child tables, else the `UPDATE` will fail.

```
ProductImage
------------------------------------
ProductID (primary key, foreign key to Product table)
FullImageID (primary key, foreign key to Image table)
ThumbImageID (foreign key; shouldn't this field be in the Image table?)
OrderNumber TINYINT (only here if ordering is per Product, else is in Image table)
```

---

The *only* reason I can see for adding a surrogate key in this situation is if there is a requirement from some other software. Things such as SQL Server Replication (or was it Service Broker?) and/or Entity Framework and/or Full-Text Search. Not sure if those examples do require it, but I have definitely seen 1 or 2 "features" that require a single-field PK.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yep, that's what I thought. But got an objection from a co-worker mentioning that without a primary key it might be harder to manage those images (remove, or reorder; each product has a set of images associated with it in a pre-defined order).

Comment: @GriefCoder There might be some confusion of terms here. There is a PK, but a Primary Key is not the same thing as an IDENTITY field / surrogate key. Quite often a surrogate key (auto increment field of some nature) is chosen as the Primary Key, but it doesn't need to be that way. You use a surrogate key when you have no other fields that can, in combination, uniquely and reliably (i.e. doesn't change) identify a row. This is why the PK here is defined on both FK fields, because you can't have the same image twice for the same Product. Adding a surrogate key wouldn't add any uniqueness here.

Comment: I see.. Why do you prefer using these two FKs as a primary key as opposed to a combination of `ProductID` and `IndexNumber` fields?

Comment: @GriefCoder I updated my answer with details that hopefully cover the various questions so far and what would likely some follow-up questions :-).

Comment: The only time I might consider a surrogate key in this case is if the many-to-many table itself wan parent to other child tables and then it could improve the joins, as it stands right now the surrogate adds nothing. And for the record, I am a person who comes down on the surrogate key side of the religious war.

Comment: If you chose to use a surrogate key, you would also need a unique index on the natural key.

Comment: @HLGEM I am not dead-set against surrogate keys, just against the needless use of them ;-). So, just out of curiosity (since I did address the fact that someone would claim to want that here to make JOINs easier if there were child tables ;-), how do you see that making things easier? Just in terms of coding? Performance? Both? In my experience, it has added quite a bit of confusion since everyone always really wanted the fields in the "natural key" we had LOTS of extra JOINs. Even if it saves some in one spot, I _personally_ think it adds too much elsewhere. But interested in your thoughts.

Comment: @HLGEM I just updated my paragraph about using a surrogate key when there are child tables involved. I also added a note at the end about the only _reasonable_ reason to add a surrogate key here that I had forgotten about earlier ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is by having three tables, one for products, one for images and one for their relationship

```
products
--------
+ product_id (pk)
- product_name
- product_description
- ...

images
------
+ image_id (pk)
- image_title
- ...

product_images
--------------
+ product_id (fk)
+ image_id (fk)
```

Comment: The question is about the `ProductImage` (many-to-many) table.. Please, read the question.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have seperate tables for fullImage and thumbImage?
Table1 is better since it allows you identify individual rows inside the table.

Table2, im sure you can't have two primary keys.
It might be better to have an Image table as follows.

```
ImageId (primary)
FullImage [actual value/FK]
ThumbNail [actual value/FK]
```

and then,

```
ProductImageID (primary)
ProductID [FK]
ImageID [FK]
```

How that helps,
Regards,
Rainy